# Why is getFields() returning an empty object?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am working on a Google Data Studio community connector, and I am trying to display only one field to start with. All of the code is in the code.gs file, except getAuthType() and isAdminUser() is in Auth.gs.

The issue is that once getData() is called, getFields() returns an empty object. Here is the log:
[image]

It looks like getSchema() is working correctly, here is the log from that function:
[image]

Here is the getFields() function:

```js
function getFields() {
   
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;

  
    fields
    .newDimension()
    .setId('device')
    .setName('Device')
    .setType(types.TEXT);

    return fields;

 }
```

Here is getData():

```js
function getData(request){
   console.log('getData request', request);
   request.configParams = validateConfig(request.configParams);
 
   console.log('getFields()', getFields(), typeof getFields());
   var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(
     
     request.fields.map(function(field){
       return field.name;
     })
   );

   try{
     console.log('start request');
  
     var apiResponse = fetchDataFromApi(request);
     var data = formatData(apiResponse, requestedFields);
   }catch (e){
     cc.newUserError()
      .setDebugText('Error fetching data from API. Exception details: ' + e)
      .setText(
        'The connector has encountered an unrecoverable error. Please Try again later.'
      )
      .throwException();
   }

   return {
     schema: requestedFields.build(),
     rows: data,
   }
 }
```

getSchema():

```js
function getSchema(request){
   var schema = {schema: getFields().build()};
   console.log(schema);
   return schema;
 }
```

The community connector is initialized outside of all functions in the same file:

```js
 var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
```

I looked through the documentation, but I cannot find anything that would cause getFields() to return an empty object, based off what I have. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that getFields() returning an empty object was causing my app to display the fields incorrectly, but the issue was that the data I was passing to the app was in the incorrect format.

getFields() isn't useful until it is called with build() (i.e. getFields().build() )

I think it is expected behavior to receive an empty object for getFields() alone.

Comment: In `getFields()` you're returning an instace of an object created by `CommunityConnector`, that is a `Field` object (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/community-connector#getFields()). If you check the documentation of the `Field` class (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/fields), the `build()` method transforms its contents in a plain `Object[]` type, supposed to be used by DataStudio and easyer to print in the console.